# My current timeline chart replaces all the previous charts in a table

Tags: jsp

I am using jsp:include tag to show the result of one jsp file in another jsp file.The included jsp file generates a timeline chart. And jsp:include tag is inside an iterator,result of each iteration is shown in a table, now each time while iterating, chart generated is replacing the previously generated charts in the table.Anyone please help me,Why charts are replaced every time???

```
    <s:iterator value="testlist">
     <tr>
      <td>
       <s:property value="tname"/>
      </td>
      <%request.getSession().setAttribute("inc",y);%>
      <td align="center">
       <jsp:include page="/per.jsp" />
      </td>
     </tr>
    </s:iterator>
```

**per.jsp:**

```
    <%y=Integer.parseInt(request.getSession().getAttribute("inc").toString());
    chart_div="chart"+y;%>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//code for chart generation</script>
    <table border="1">
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div id="<%=chart_div %>" style='width: 1000px; height: 440px;'></div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Here id of div tag changes everytime during iteration, eventhough previous charts are replaced with the newly generated one.

Comment: please post the relevant codes of your question, we can't help without taking a look at it

Answer (score 0):

because that is in a loop so it is calling that jsp page every time that's why the result are shown different each time.

Comment: On iterating each time,variable values of charts in included jsp file are getting changed.But the chart is replaced everytime on each iteration with the newly created chart.

Comment: thanks,your code seems fine if it is exactly as you are using

Comment: thank you... this is the exact code.. but charts are getting replaced every time

Comment: are you taking any parameter from jsp in javascript for generating chart??

Comment: yes.. values needed for x,y axis are taken from jsp to javascript while generating chart..

Comment: i think the problem is in your javascript,may me you are adding the html if this is case then use append.